# Expression.Call usage

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have tried to convert the string to `ToLower` case using the below Expression call.

```
var tolowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethods().Where(m => m.Name == "ToString").FirstOrDefault(); 
var toLowerMethodCall = Expression.Call(memExp,tolowerMethod,new Expression[0]);
```

I am facing some issue to create an Expression call to format a value like: `"05/12/2012 12:00:00"` to `{0:MM/dd/yyyy}`.

Comment: What language is this?? Please tag the question with it

Comment: What errors do you get, or what is going wrong? I can see that there are parens missing at the call of `new Expression[0]`, but I guess that's a typo?

Comment: Your issue does not make sense. There is not even a normal method that can do that.

Comment: Your issue says you want to convert a string to lowercase, then the actual code uses `ToString`, then your final paragraph says you want to format a `DateTime`. What do you actually want?

Answer (score 18):

Well there's no such method that can take a date string in one format and reformat it to another.  You'd have to convert that string to a `DateTime` then back to a `string`.

Here's how you could create such a lambda:

```
var dateStr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(string));
// call static method "DateTime.Parse"
var asDateTime = Expression.Call(typeof(DateTime), "Parse", null, dateStr);
var fmtExpr = Expression.Constant("MM/dd/yyyy");
// call instance method "DateTime.ToString(string)"
var body = Expression.Call(asDateTime, "ToString", null, fmtExpr); 
var lambdaExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, string>>(body, dateStr);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
(string date) => DateTime.Parse(date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Then compile and call it.

```
var method = lambdaExpr.Compile();
method("05/12/2012 12:00:00"); // "05/12/2012"
```